# how to change standard header value in restlets?

Tags: http, http-headers, restlet, http-get, restlet-2.0

I have the following get:

```
@Get
public String represent(Variant variant) throws ResourceException
{
    String text = "returntext";

    text+="\r\n";
    return text;
}
```

The response from invoking this service:

CFG - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2013 19:59:37 GMT
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.9
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Length: 118
Connection: keep-alive

How do I change the connection header value to close ?

I think this maybe a restlet bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the server closes the connection or not, depends on whether the client request asks for the connection to close or not.

Here is a sample Server code:

```
import org.restlet.data.Form;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.data.Parameter;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import org.restlet.util.Series;

public class TestRestlet extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public String getImpl(){
        return "Sample Response Text\r\n";
    }
}
```

And here is what i got on linux commmand line (using only telnet):
[Please note that the last line in request-header in each request is followed by 2 *newlines*] [To avoid any confusion, some of the requests do not contain request-body.]

```
[root@mylinuxserver]# telnet 172.16.101.34 6060
Trying 172.16.101.34...
Connected to win7comp01 (172.16.101.34).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.34:6060

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C2E77F4D0437E525A0FC66498EF09E8B; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:25:44 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22

Sample Response Text

GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.34:6060
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1873DE26443F5DF62379B895AEA0F004; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:25:48 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22

Sample Response Text

GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.34:6060
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=43EC7C9AACC6C0CEF6FAC8F608B1D79C; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:25:57 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22
Connection: close

Sample Response Text
Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@mylinuxserver]# telnet 172.16.101.34 6060
Trying 172.16.101.34...
Connected to win7comp01 (172.16.101.34).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2C879A91F2501DD9D3B39EF50C3F46CA; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:26:09 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22
Connection: close

Sample Response Text
Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@mylinuxserver]# telnet 172.16.101.34 6060
Trying 172.16.101.34...
Connected to win7comp01 (172.16.101.34).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /TestRestlet

Sample Response Text
Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@mylinuxserver]#
```

In the above examples, several types of HTTP connections are made.

The response to the 1st request:

```
GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.34:6060
```

[Note: the line `Host: 172.16.101.34:6060` is followed by 2 `\r\n`: `\r\n\r\n`]

is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C2E77F4D0437E525A0FC66498EF09E8B; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:25:44 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22

Sample Response Text
```

The connection is not closed yet, and we send another request:

```
GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.34:6060
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

That gets the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1873DE26443F5DF62379B895AEA0F004; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:25:48 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22
```

Still the connection is not closed.

However on the 3rd request:

```
GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.34:6060
Connection: close
```

The connection is closed, because the request contains `Connection: close` header.
You can see the telnet exits after displaying a message: `Connection closed by foreign host.`

There are 2 more sample request-response in the above given examples:

1.An HTTP 1.0 request:

```
GET /TestRestlet HTTP/1.0
```

With response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2C879A91F2501DD9D3B39EF50C3F46CA; Path=/hotelSoft
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 08:26:09 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.0.15
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 22
Connection: close

Sample Response Text
```

And the telnet exits after displaying: `Connection closed by foreign host.`

2.A request without HTTP version mentioned:

```
GET /TestRestlet
```

And response is: (Without headers)

```
Sample Response Text
```

And the telnet exits with a message:  `Connection closed by foreign host.`

Conclusion:

Whatever is your client / client-program , make it send an HTTP-1.0 request , or a HTTP-1.1 request with `Connection: close` header.

In Java, you achieve this by:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
.
.
.
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://....").openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","close");
// rest of the code here....
```

Also check if a statement like this:

```
httpURLConnection.disconnect();
```

can help you disconnect the connection.